# What is "panel-type specifications" more general than "two-way fixed effects"?

Tags: econometrics, nonexpert

[Borusyak, 2021](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/b1e55330-f605-363c-b07f-3ab67325e929/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B47d22c8f-e7ba-3ead-9833-eeae8a94d5f0%7D) has a sentence

> While our baseline setting is for panel data with two-way fixed
> effects, we show how our formal results extend naturally in a number
> of ways. We allow for **more general panel-type specifications that can
> include, for instance, unit-specific trends or time-varying covariates**

It is quite contradictory to my understanding. Because to me, when you consider "two-way fixed effects", you also control for unit and period fixed effects. Why the author used the word "**more general panel-type specifications that can include, for instance, unit-specific trends or time-varying covariates**" here. I mean, the "more general panel-type specifications" as he described is "two-way fixed effects", not "more general"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two-way FE model is:

$y_{it} = \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{it} +\gamma_i + \delta_t +u_{it}$

The $\delta_t$ absorb average time effects, but there may still be unit-specific trends, which could be modelled with:

$y_{it} = \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{it} +\alpha_i t +\gamma_i + \delta_t +u_{it}$

There is not a violation of multicollinearity and it is more general than before. If instead we had a *general* time trend, rather than unit specific, it would violate multicollinearity.

$y_{it} = \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{it} +\alpha t +\gamma_i + \delta_t +u_{it}$

Also, there has been some literature that has cautioned against the use of individual-specific time trends because such can absorb part of a heterogeneous treatment effect. [Meer and West 2016](http://Meer,%20J.,%20&%20West,%20J.%20(2016).%20Effects%20of%20the%20minimum%20wage%20on%20employment%20dynamics.%20Journal%20of%20Human%20Resources,%2051(2),%20500-522.).

Comment: Thank @Micheal , can I ask an example of controlling for "unit-specific trends" is unit's lag variable?

Comment: "general time trend" would be perfect colinear with time fixed effect, is it what you mean then? Thanks

Comment: Lag variable is different than time trends.  A lag variable might be as follows:
$y_{it} = \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{it} + \beta_2 Z_{it-1} +\gamma_i +\delta_t +u_{it}
$Z$ is used generically. $Z$ could be a lagged $X$ variable, or instead a lagged outcome variable. There are issues with lagged outcome variables, and I'm guessing that's not relevant to your case.

Comment: ""general time trend" would be perfect colinear with time fixed effect, is it what you mean then?"  Yes.

Comment: Can I ask for an example of adding a unit-specific trends if it is convenient? Thanks a heaps

Comment: The second equation in my answer does this. The coefficient, $\alpha_i$, differs for each individual, measuring an unit-specific time trend.

Comment: ah, now I see, thanks Micheal